# Prove that the equation $x^2+7x=-12$ has exactly two distinct solutions in $\mathbb{Z}p$, for every prime $p$.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that the equation $x^2+7x=-12$ has exactly two distinct solutions in $\mathbb{Z}p$, for every prime $p$. Is this true for every positive integer $p > 1$?

So far I'll I have done is factored the equation into $(x+4)(x+3)=0$ which will have two distinct solutions: $x=-4$ or $x=-3$. Now I'm not sure how to say this will always have two distinct solutions for any $\mathbb{Z}p$

Comment: Argue that $p - 4$ and $p - 3$ are different in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all $p$ prime.

Comment: Use the fact that $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a field, thus it is an integral domain, thus it has no zero divisors

Comment: Yes, use what Rob Bland said as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being prime is not the key here. Being odd is.

For odd $p$ (not necessarily prime), $2$ is invertible mod $p$ and so the quadratic formula applies.
Then note that the discriminant of $x^2+7x+12$ is $1$, which is a square and never $0$ mod $p$. The quadratic formula gives us exactly two solutions.

For $p=2$, the equation reduces to $x^2+x=0$, whose solutions are $0$ and $1$.

For $p>2$ even, this does not necessarily hold. It fails for $p=6$ for instance, because $x^2+7x+12$ has $4$ roots mod $6$: $0,2,3,5$. Also, there are $8$ roots mod $30$, for instance.